# Process signals to do a graceful exit with a nodejs app on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, signals, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have this Nodejs app that runs in Elastic Beanstalk. I'd like to do some cleaning when the application exits (e.g new version is deployed, restarting the app server). To do so I'm listening to some events & signals, but none of them seems to be triggered. Here's the code from *app.js*:

```
process.on("SIGTERM", function() {
  console.log("SIGTERM, clean");
  process.exit(0);
});

process.on("exit", function(code) {
  console.log("Process exiting with code " + code);
});

process.on("uncaughtException", function() {
  console.log("Unhandled exception occurred);
  process.exit(99);
});
```

When I restart the app through the management console, I don't see anything in the log, even though a new node process is created and the old one is killed.
If I manually kill the process I can see the log messages in the output. Does that mean Beanstalk-triggered events do not send kill signals? If so, how is it possible to do some graceful exit?

**Edit**: here's the result of more investigation.
Beanstalk uses Upstart to manage the application. In /etc/init/nodejs, there's this line:

```
exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'PATH=$PATH:$NODE_HOME/bin $EB_NODE_COMMAND 2>&1' nodejs >> /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
```

Which runs `npm start`, which starts the application using the *package.json* config. Here's the process tree I have:

```
root     29155  su -s /bin/sh -c PATH=$PATH:$NODE_HOME/bin $EB_NODE_COMMAND 2>&1 nodejs
nodejs   29156   \_ sh -c PATH=$PATH:$NODE_HOME/bin $EB_NODE_COMMAND 2>&1
nodejs   29157    \_ npm                                                                                                                             
nodejs   29168     \_ node app/app.js
```

`initctl status nodejs` show the pid of the first process. So I guess Upstart sends a **SIGTERM** to this process, which does not forward it all the way to my process. Unfortunately I still have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: Any update on this? Did you figure out a way?

Comment: @clay: nope, no update from AWS support and no solution on my end. Have tried the alternative way proposed by @pcothenet?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I might have to try that "undocumented and unsupported" script . . . just wish there was a better way! I was hoping Node beanstalk would have had an update in this area, but think at lot of focus was on Docker beanstalk and perhaps options like that exist there. Cleanly shutting down a server should be important!

Comment: Looks like this is still the state as of today, does anyone have a better understanding of why this is?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, AWS support confirmed that there is no workaround for now. A feature request has been created for the Beanstalk dev team, but who knows when that gets implemented.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an undocumented way to "intercept" the SIGKILL by adding a script to the `hooks/appdeploy` folder:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=493887

This is pretty much undocumented and unsupported by the AWS support pointed me to this.